# how to pass multiple variables using self.location

Tags: javascript, php, reload

i cant pass and get variables using  self.location on  reload function when choosing dropdown value.

i got only the first value that i passed through url,how to pass the value from the second dropdown through this samr url dd-mysqli.php

```
@$cat=$_GET['cat']; 
@$subcat=$_GET['subcat'];// Use this line or below line if register_global is off
if(strlen($cat) > 0 and !is_numeric($cat)){ // to check if $cat is numeric data or not. 
echo "Data Error";
exit;
}

?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$cat=$_POST['cat'];
$subcat=$_POST['subcat'];

echo "Value of \$cat = $cat <br>Value of \$subcat = $subcat ";}
?>


<html>

<head>
<title>Multiple drop down list box from plus2net</title>
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript>
<!--
function reload(form)
{
var val=form.cat.options[form.cat.options.selectedIndex].value;
    var val2=form.subcat.options[form.subcat.options.selectedIndex].value;


    self.location='dd-mysqli.php?cat=' + val + '&subcat=' + val2;
}
//-->

</script>

  echo "<form method=post name=f1 action='dd-mysqli.php'>";
//////////        Starting of first drop downlist /////////
echo "<select name='cat' onchange=\"reload(this.form)\"><option value=''>Select one</option>";
if($stmt = $connection->query("$query2")){
    while ($row2 = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
    if($row2['id']==@$cat){echo "<option selected value='$row2[id]'>$row2[category_description]</option>";}
else{echo  "<option value='$row2[id]'>$row2[category_description]</option>";}

  }
}else{
echo $connection->error;
}

echo "</select>";
//////////////////  This will end the first drop down list ///////////
echo "<select name='subcat'  onchange=\"reload(this.form)\"><option value=''>Select one</option>";
if(isset($cat) and strlen($cat) > 0){
if($stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM category AS c INNER JOIN category_language AS cl ON c.id=cl.category_id where parent_id=? && lang_id='1' ORDER BY category_description")){
$stmt->bind_param('i',$cat);
$stmt->execute();
 $result = $stmt->get_result();
 while ($row1 = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     if($row1['id']==@subcat){echo "<option selected value='$row1[id]'>$row1[category_description]</option>";}
 else{echo  "<option value='$row1[id]'>$row1[category_description]</option>";}

  }

}
```

how can i solve this

Comment: Ananthu, welcome as a new SO poster.  Your post would be greatly enhanced with a little more thought on how you word your question. For example, include what programming language the problem is within in your question would help others.

Comment: It's because of how you're using your `reload` function, it does get called whenever you change the value of one of the selects which triggers the location change.

Comment: whisch function using instead of reload